# kstreams grouping on two fields to get the count

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Can we groupby two fields(one is key and another value) and get the count in kstreams.

I want to get distinct counts of userid(value) for each pid(key).groupByKey will not give the distinct userid's.
I tried to use groupBy instead of groupByKey but seeing syntax errors. Can someone help?

```
   KStream<Integer, Integer> stream = events.map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<Integer, Integer>(value.getpid(), value.getUserId()));

   KGroupedStream<Integer, Integer> groupedStream = stream.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.Integer());
```

Comment: Please specify the error you are getting.

Comment: i tried changing groupbykey to groupby in the above kgroupedstream and error is kstream cannot be applied to`(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped<java.lang.integer,java.lang.integer>)`.What is the right way to groupby two fields

Comment: It's because `groupBy` does not have overloaded method to accept `Grouped`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count by user-id and pid, you can put both as a Pojo into the key:

```java
KStream<UserPid, Integer> stream =
    events.selectKey((key, value) -> new UserPid(value.getpid(), value.getUserId()));
KGroupedStream<Integer, Integer> groupedStream =
    stream.groupByKey(Grouped.with(new UserPidSerde(), Serdes.Integer());
```

You need to create a corresponding POJO class `UserPid` and serde class `UserPidSerde extends Serde<UserPid>`.

Comment: Thanks Matthias,i see some examples for serdes at https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.0/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html.Do i have to implement custom serde to use UserPidSerde ?

Comment: Yes. You need to create a custom serde for `UserPid` class.

Comment: After creating custom serde `UserPidSerde` i am seeing error "Cannot resolve method 'groupByKey(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped<K,V>)'  for this line `KGroupedStream<Integer, Integer> groupedStream =
    stream.groupByKey(Grouped.with(new UserPidSerde(), Serdes.Integer()));

Comment: Also my final result should be pid ,count(distinct userid).How to accomplish this if i use UserPid POJO?

Comment: Well, `KGroupedStream<Integer, Integer> groupedStream` should be `KGroupedStream< UserPid, Integer> groupedStream` I guess.

Comment: tried that as well and still getting the same error.

Comment: It's hard to help over Stackoverflow as your question is not concrete, but you stumble from problem to problem. I would recommend to use Confluent Community Slack (*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent*). It's for free to sign up. https://launchpass.com/confluentcommunity

Answer (score -1):

Since you need distinct count of user(value) for each pid(key), you need to first use `groupByKey` which will group all `users` with same `pid`. Then you need to aggregate to form `set` of `user`(to get unique users). After that just get size of `set` and you will get count of distinct users for each pid.

```
KStream<Integer, Integer> stream = events.map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<Integer, Integer>(value.getpid(), value.getUserId()));
KStream<Integer, Integer> output = stream.groupByKey().
            aggregate((Initializer<Set<Integer>>) HashSet::new,
                    (k, v, current) -> {current.add(v); return current;}).mapValues(Set::size).toStream();
```